# XSLT min between two variables not behaving as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to select the first PromotedProgramme based on:

- Promoted Programme Type
- MovieOrEvent

Then if more than one type exists to select the first seq_number.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<PromoMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PromotedProgramme type="MovieOrEvent" seq_number="1">
    <TitleId>000000218564</TitleId>
    <ExternalProgId>785432</ExternalProgId>
    <TitleBroadcastRef>078654</TitleBroadcastRef>
    <TitleName>Men In Black</TitleName>
  </PromotedProgramme>
  <PromotedProgramme type="MovieOrEvent" seq_number="2">
    <SlotId>675342</SlotId>
    <SlotName>Late Movie</SlotName>
    <TitleId>000000218576</TitleId>
    <ExternalProgId>785632</ExternalProgId>
    <TitleBroadcastRef>078123</TitleBroadcastRef>
    <TitleName>Die Hard</TitleName>
    <EPGTitleName>Die Hard</EPGTitleName>
  </PromotedProgramme>
</PromoMessage>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <PromoMessage>
      <!-- Create Variable To Find the First Sequence Numbers -->
      <xsl:variable name="LOW" select="min(//PromotedProgramme/@seq_number)" />
      <xsl:variable name="EMOE" select="boolean(//PromotedProgramme/@type='MovieOrEvent')" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <!--Promoted Programme Type MovieOrEvent-->
        <xsl:when test="$LOW and $EMOE">
          <xsl:attribute name="title">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="//TitleName &gt;'0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="//TitleName" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="//EPGTitleName &gt;'0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="//EPGTitleName" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="//SeasonName &gt;'0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="//SeasonName" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="//SlotName &gt;'0'">
                <xsl:value-of select="//SlotName" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:if test="//TitleBroadcasterRef &gt; '0'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="//Intestitial/@name" />
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <Programme>
            <ProgrammeId>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//ExternalProgId &gt; '0'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="//ExternalProgId" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="//TitleId &gt; '0'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="//TitleId" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="//SlotId &gt; '0'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="//SlotId" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="//PromotedBroadcasterRef &gt; '0'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="//PromotedBroadcasterRef" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:if test="//TitleBroadcasterRef &gt; '0'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//TitleBroadcasterRef" />
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </ProgrammeId>
          </Programme>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </PromoMessage>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However when i run this the Title, ProgrammeID fields are populated with more than one result. The variables i'm attempting to implement are EMOE and LOW which I want to select the first PromotedProgrammeType and the minimum seq_number of that PromotedProgramme Type.

EG: In the XML example above the result i'm looking for is it to pick up the first PromotedProgramme Only.

In the Result it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PromoMessage title="Men In Black" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Programme>
    <ProgrammeId>785432</ProgrammeId>
  </Programme>
</PromoMessage>
```

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Please provide a [***Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much all i want to know is how to call a variable to work out a promotedProgramme type and limit the result to only the first seq_number found: EG: MovieOrEvent is used, only use the first seq_number. Currently my output for this in the Title and ProgrammeID Attributes are outputting 3 results, Thanks, Simon

Comment: Please provide a [***MINIMAL*, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  If you want to claim that "*XSLT min between two variables not behaving as expected*", the burden is on *you* to show how that is so, it should not be on *us* to dig through your extraneous code.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks @kjhughes understood. I have cut down the original code to only focus around the issue. In the title and ProgrammeId are outputting multiple results from the XML when i want to limit it to just one. What i'm attempting to use is the two variables EMOE and LOW to work out the first PromotedProgrammeType and by the first seq_number found. NOTE: I have only included MovieOrEvent as a Promoted Programme Type here but there are more that could possibly show up. I hope that better explains the issue i face, Thanks, Simon

Comment: I (still) don't understand your question. Could you expand, in plain language, on what the task is here? What you did (and isn't working) doesn't really help in understanding what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code.  I'm not going to attempt a rewrite, but I'll get you headed in the right direction:

1. The reason `@title` and `ProgrammeId` are being populated with more
   than one result is that you are misusing the `//` XPath descendant-or-self step.  When
   you select, say, `//TitleName`, you are selecting all of the
   `TitleName` elements in the document.  That's not what you want. 
   You want to select a particular `PromotedProgramme`, then select
   only its `TitleName`.   The XSLT would look something like this:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="theProgrammeIWant"
                 select="/PromoMessage/PromotedProgramme[@seq_number = '1']"/>
   ```

   You may well have a more complicated predicate -- I just can't tell what it is from your question --
   but you have to be aware of how to write predicates of the above form.
2. Your `xsl:when test="//TitleName"` tests are also not likely what you want.  It looks 
   like what you might mean is `$theProgrammeIWant/TitleName` to test if the program you
   want has a `TitleName`.  Get this pattern right, then replicate for each occurrence in your code.
3. Don't avoid learning the basics.  I'd recommend reading some fundamental background material such as Michael Kay's book on XSLT.

I hope these tips help you get past your impasse.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it actually does what I need using the seg_number = '1'. Originally it was more complicated. Removing the xpath descendant and using a variable. Appreciate the tip on the book, definitely looking that up.

Comment: @Simian7, you're welcome.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  You might also consider accepting the answer you got to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26353278/290085).  Thanks.